# Firefox doesn't resolve onion addresses

Tags: firefox, transparent-proxy

I'm looking for this option in `about:config` for firefox, to access to onion domains.

I've configured [anonymous user](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy#LocalRedirectionThroughTor) on my Ubuntu:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m tcp --dport 9040 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -j DROP
```

Tor well configured too.

Dns works:

```
$ dig @127.0.0.1 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50585
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             60      IN      A       74.125.224.67

;; Query time: 293 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 22 19:07:47 NOVT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

But firefox doesn't correctly looking for onion domains. It looks for www.hash.onion, etc. Thereafter `Server not found`.

In this case, my firefox is anonymized. I'm getting `Congratulation` from `check.torproject.org`. But Inner Tor Network with onion domains is not accessible.

I have already set:

`network.proxy.socks_remote_dns = true`

Comment: are you not using the tor browser bundle?

Comment: No, default Ubuntu's firefox. I'm trying to configure it.

Comment: its recommended you use the browser bundle. Why are you trying to configure the default?

Comment: also what do you mean by looks for www.hash.onion? onion sites don't have www.

Comment: exactly this I've meant. Instead of downloading the page, firefox trying to resolve hash.onion domain via tor-dns sub-server, thereafter its tries to resolve www.hash.onion domain. Thereafter fails.

Comment: by hash you don't mean literally the word hash, you mean the correct .onion host name right? also this is bizarre

Comment: how come you're sending to port 9040? shouldn't it be 9050?

Comment: This is TransPort: `9040` and `TransListenAddress 127.0.0.1`

Comment: See, https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy#LocalRedirectionThroughTor

Comment: Do you have "VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10" and "AutomapHostsOnResolve 1" lines in torrc? Hidden service URLs don't use DNS, and won't resolve without those lines. Also, to avoid the "www" issue, you need to edit about:config, and turn off "browser.fixup.alternate.*".

Answer (score 3):

For the transparent proxy functionality of Tor to work you also need to set Tor as your DNS server, normally by setting the DNSPort torrc option to 53 and changing your /etc/resolv.conf. See the [TransPort instructions](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy#LocalRedirectionThroughTor) for more hints. Without altering your resolver settings, DNS requests will go out to the Internet – not only leaking DNS but also failing to resolve .onion addresses.

However, as puser has said, the transparent proxy feature is not safe for web browsing. Malicious websites can send traffic to your web browsing causing it to de-anonymise you. The Tor Browser Bundle was specifically designed to defend against these threats.

Answer (score 1):

**Closed.**

This was wrong iptables redirect rule that excludes loop from redirect devices:

Was:

```
#iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
```

Fix:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -m owner --uid-owner anonymous -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
```

Cause:

```
/etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

bind by dnsmasq, instead of external IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In the search bar, type `about:config` and accept the risk to continue.

Then find the variable `network.dns.blockDotOnion` and change it to **false**. If your network configuration was done correctly, firefox should now be able to resolve .onion addresses.